# Meaning of completeness for a sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I am studying some course notes and came across the following proposition:

"An orthonormal sequence in a Hilbert space H is complete iff the only vector in H which is orthogonal to each of the vectors in the sequence is the null vector"

What I am not sure about however, is what it means for a sequence to be complete. I understand what completeness is for a space (every couchy sequence converges within the space), but what does it mean for a sequence to be complete?

I did not find this definition anywhere in my notes.

Thanks

Comment: A family/sequence of orthonormal vectors in an Hilbert space $H$ is said to be complete if its linear span is a dense subspace of $H$.

Comment: One is using the same word for different things. How many (mathematical) meanings of "normal" can you recall?

Comment: [Here's Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_space#Orthonormal_bases)'s definition, by the way.

Comment: No, @user251257, I did not. I just shared a link containing a more precise explanation of the meaning of "complete system" in a Hilbert space. But it's basically a repetition of my other comment.

Comment: @user251257 Which two properties are you talking about?

Comment: @user251257 I might have misunderstood the question. I thought the part between inverted commas was a theorem, the hypothesis of which was obscure to the OP.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli it is said a proposition in op ...  Probably my bad. Sorry.